# Xamarin Forms Check Internet Connectivity

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to check the internet connection using Xamarin. I am currently following the tutorial of **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVXVs_CHxAU&t=132s**.
 
I am getting an error of **"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"**. What may cause this? and how can it be fixed?
 
I am using **Xam.Plugin.Connectivity v3.2.0** for the record I tried using older version of this nuget package still same error occurs. I am using Xamarin Live in my debugging. I already added **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET** to my android manifest.

**XAML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TBSApplication"
             x:Class="TBSApplication.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button x:Name="Btn" Text="Check Connectivity" Clicked="Btn_Clicked"/>
                <Label x:Name="Lbl" Text="Status"/>
                <Label x:Name="Lbl1" Text="Type:"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**XAML.cs Code:**

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TBSApplication
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;

                if (isConnected == true)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Message", "Connected", "Ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Message", "Not Connected", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Message", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed Connectivity plugin against PCL AND your platform specific projects - Android, iOS ? The error only occurs when you press your button?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro In a question I read that you need to  request those resources at the time you need. Check if that is reason n your case.

Comment: Yes sir @BrunoCaceiro I even try to install the plugin in a shared or .net type still same error

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta any ideas on how to fix these?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? And where it really occurs.

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I write a demo using your code, (no permission needed in case of android) and it's work fine check https://github.com/anirudhagupta/ConnectivityChecker

Comment: @Lawrence Agulto .Try using the Xamarin Essentials Nuget which is in pre -release. I have successfully tried their Internet Connection Check.  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/index?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms)

Comment: @mohammedmazin Do I need to modify anything before I test? Or just copy the code?

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Why when I tried this error shows?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro there is no error the error only occurs when I clicked the button and it shows in the catch exception part

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto try run the file main.xaml.cs it's have 5 line code and it's work fine in my phone.

Comment: Add this in MainActivity.cs . `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);` .Try to use physical device or Android emulator to test

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Xamarin Live Player to test your app. Xamarin Live Player is good for testing designs navigations but in terms of functionality it is not functioning well. Try using emulators or mobile devices itself by enabling Developer mode.